# Login authentication error

Tags: authentication

Unable to login. Screen shows my name above oscillating password box. Authentication error notice. Unable to enter password

This was after failing to install update hplip. Lookup suggested first purging python then python3. This seems to have deleted Firefox and Thunderbird as well as hplip etc

Trying to login 1 hour later failed as above

Comment: Purging python & python3 will likely have remove critical components of the desktop experience. Try logging into a terminal via CTRL+ALT+F1, then `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop^` (note the caret) to put back applications which were erroneously removed.

Comment: Hi @Ian, did you find any solution for this? I'm also facing the same problem. Right now, as a workaround, I'm logging into tty3 console and run `sudo loginctl unlock-sessions` to unlock the sessions. Which works but I've not found the actual solution.